# VLOOKUPNTH Cell show "#value"

Tags: excel, vba

My document consists of parts for production and alot of my data is from data warehouse queries that my company have.

The problem:

When I update my queries/document, all the cells that have my `VLOOKUPNTH` formula shows the value `"#value"` UNTIL I manually click the formula bar and press enter. Then it works perfect.

Problem is as soon as I update my program I have to manually press every single cell with this function and press enter in the function bar (It's around 15x3 cells).

My code:

```
Function VLOOKUPNTH(Lookup_value, table_array As Range, _
Col_index_num As Integer, Nth_value)
 ' Extension to VLOOKUP function.  Allows for finding
 ' the   "  nth  "   item that matches the lookup value.

Dim nRow As Long
Dim nVal As Integer
Dim bFound As Boolean
VLOOKUPNTH = ""
With table_array
    For nRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If .Cells(nRow, 1).Value = Lookup_value Then
            nVal = nVal + 1
        End If
        If nVal = Nth_value Then
            VLOOKUPNTH = .Cells(nRow, Col_index_num).Text
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next nRow
End With
End Function
```

Picture:

[image: pic]

Is there any smart way of avoiding this issue? Can I somehow activate this function with VBA code? OBS! In the picture above its only the most right column that is changed, my misstake. OBS!

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile

Comment: Thank you for this information! I had no idea this was possible i will check it out right now.

Comment: I tried it out, and now i only have to press enter in one function bar and all of them becomes the proper value wich is very nice!

Comment: Hitting Ctrl/Alt/F9 might also work

Comment: ctrl+alt+F9 worked to! Is that a command that can i can make a macro with? Or can i do this command with VBA code?

Comment: If anyone of you answere this post with your comment i could make this ticket resolved! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the sheet or sheets where you use this function, you can add an event.  Do this by right clicking on the sheet name (Sheet1 for example) and selecting "View Code" from the pop-up menu.

In the left drop-down box of the code window, select Worksheet.  Then in the right drop down select the "Change" event.  Use the Worksheets Calculate method and you have your Ctrl/Alt/F9 - but only for the sheet.  If you want to calculate the entire workbook, then use the Application.Calculate method.

Make any change to the sheet and all the functions on the sheet calculate.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     ws.Calculate    
End Sub
```